# Non-time orientable quotient of de Sitter space

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, time, topology

Examples of non-time orientable spacetimes are pretty scarce, but it seems the big one is quotients of de Sitter space of the form $dS^n/\pi_1$, where $\pi_1$ is some subgroup of the isometries of de Sitter space. The standard example, as seen in Hawking and Ellis (p. 130) and [Calabi and Markus's paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970419?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) is $dS^2/\mathbb{Z}_2$, with $\mathbb{Z}_2$ being, for instance, the transformation $(t,\chi) \rightarrow (-t, \chi + \pi)$, on the metric of de Sitter space

\begin{equation}
ds^2 = -dt^2 + \alpha^2 \cosh^2(\alpha^{-1}t) d\chi^2
\end{equation}

Which I assume means that the points $t$ are identified with the points $-t$ (basically identifying the lower half with the upper half of the hyperboloid of de Sitter space) and identifying the antipodal points of $\chi$.

The simplest geodesic for de Sitter space is just $U^\mu = (1,0)$. In this situation, I would think that it would come from timelike infinity, head towards the hypersurface of $t=0$, and then "bounce back" backward.

Does this interpretation make sense? It seems a bit strange to me that a curve can just reflect like that on some boundary. Wouldn't we just be able to do the same thing with Minkowski space with the identification $t \rightarrow -t$, in this case? Or did I misunderstand the situation here? Perhaps the $\chi$ part being too neglected in this analysis.